# Why is onkeydown functioning differently than onclick?

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

this is my first time with Blazor, so apologies if this sounds stupid. Here is some Blazor code I wrote:

```
<ul>
@foreach (var tag in tags)
    {
        <li>
            @tag
            <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="() => remove(tag)">remove</button>
        </li>
    }
</ul>

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Tags</h1>

<input placeholder="Enter tag" @bind=@tag @onkeydown="enter"/>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="addTag">Add</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="clear">Clear</button>

@code {
    private string tag;

    private List<string> tags = new List<string>();

    private void addTag()
    {
        if (tags.Count() < 5)
        {
            tags.Add(tag);
            tag = string.Empty;
        }
    }
    private void enter(KeyboardEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Code == "Enter")
        {
            addTag();
        }
    }
    private void clear()
    {
        tags.Clear();
    }
    private void remove(string tag)
    {
        tags.Remove(tag);
    }
}
```

For some reason that I cannot figure out, I expected that both when the Add button is clicked, or the enter key is pressed, the behavior should be the same, i.e, the input entered in the text box will get stored in @tag, and added to the tags list. This is indeed what happens when the add button is clicked, but when the Enter key is pressed, the first tag in the list of tags is always an empty string, and then on, it is off by one. So for example:

If I put mango in the input box and hit enter, the first `<li>` item to pop up on my screen is "".
If I then put apple in the input box and hit enter, the next `<li>` item to pop up on my screen is mango.

It is off by one, and for the life of me, I cannot figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is by default the `@bind` attribute updates the value when the `change` event is fired on the input control. When you press enter the input box, the `onkeydown` event will be fired before the `change` event, so the value of the `tag` field doesn't change. To keep the value up-to-date you can do:

```
<input placeholder="Enter tag" @bind=@tag @bind:event="oninput" @onkeydown="enter"/>
```

You can also try `keyup` event, because it is fired after the `change` event:

```
<input placeholder="Enter tag" @bind=@tag @onkeyup="enter"/>
```

[ASP.NET Core Blazor data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: Sorry for the silly question, but what is `control` and what is `focus`? I read these terms a lot in the answers but never know what they mean.

Comment: Nvm! I believe this is what you were referring to: https://web.dev/focus/

Comment: input, button, etc that can receive events are controls. Yes the article explains focus.

Comment: But this wouldn't explain the fact, that if I press enter twice, the focus is not lost, but I am still able to input values? @shingo

Comment: This is a common practice that pressing enter will commit the text in an input element and firing the `change` event. By reading the linked article in my answer, we know that by default the `@bind` attribute updates the bound value when `change` event is fired, if you search on the internet about this event (e.g. [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) or [whatwg](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#concept-input-apply)), all of them will tell you the term "lose focus".

Comment: But the behaviour "pressing enter to commit" exists before these standards appeared, and modern browsers choose standstill.

Comment: So pressing `enter` is firing the `change` event, so shouldn't this update the `tag` value, since it gets updated when the `change` event is fired. How come then, that I am not seeing the expected output? @shingo

Comment: Pressing enter is firing both the `keydown` event and the `change` event, because of the order, your code is calling `addTag` in the `keydown` event, at the point the value hasn't updated, so you see an empty string. The `tag` value is just updated after it, so when you press enter the second time, you see the last input value.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem happens because of the order in which the events execute.

If you add the following code you will see that `tag` is being set.

```cs
<div class="alert alert-info">
    Tag: @tag
</div>
```

In your current setup:

1. The input is wired up the `onchanged` event (wired up by the @bind.)
2. It updates `tag` when either the input loses focus (you click somewhere else) or your click Enter.

However the `onkeydown` event occurs when you press enter i.e. before the `onchanged` event.  At this point `tag` contains the old value, it hasn't been updated yet.

You can change the event sequence by manually wiring up the input and triggering `tag` updates on the `oninput` event rather that on `onchange`.  Note I've also moved `OnEnter` to the `onkeyup` event to ensure it's called last (you can never be sure of how differtent browsers implement these events).

Here's your input:

*Version 1 - Net6.0 or earlier*

```html
<input placeholder="Enter tag" value="@this.tag" @onkeyup=this.OnEnter @oninput=this.OnInput />
```

*Version 2 - Net7.0*

```html
<input placeholder="Enter tag" @bind:get=this.tag @bind:event="oninput" @bind:set=this.OnSet @onkeyup=this.OnEnter />
```

And the UI event handlers.

```cs
    private void OnEnter(KeyboardEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Code == "Enter")
            addTag();
    }

    private void OnInput(ChangeEventArgs e)
        => tag = e.Value?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
        
    private void OnSet(string value)
        => tag = value;
```

The events now trigger in the correct order.

Here's my full demo page:

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>
<ul>
    @foreach (var tag in tags)
    {
        <li>
            @tag
            <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="() => remove(tag)">remove</button>
        </li>
    }
</ul>

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Tags</h1>

<input placeholder="Enter tag" value="@this.tag" @onkeyup=this.OnEnter @oninput=this.OnInput />
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="addTag">Add</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="clear">Clear</button>

<div>
    <input placeholder="Enter tag" @bind:get=this.tag @bind:event="oninput" @bind:set=this.OnSet @onkeyup=this.OnEnter />
</div>

<div class="alert alert-info">
    Tag: @tag
</div>

@code {
    private string tag;

    private List<string> tags = new List<string>();

    private void addTag()
    {
        if (tags.Count() < 5)
        {
            tags.Add(tag);
            tag = string.Empty;
        }
    }

    private void OnEnter(KeyboardEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Code == "Enter")
            addTag();
    }

    private void OnInput(ChangeEventArgs e)
        => tag = e.Value?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;


    private void OnSet(string value)
        => tag = value;

    private void clear()
    {
        tags.Clear();
    }
    private void remove(string tag)
    {
        tags.Remove(tag);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `onKeyUp` makes sense to me because what you are suggesting is that `onKeyUp` makes sure that that it is fired after onChange. But I am not sure I understand `<input placeholder="Enter tag" value="@this.tag" @onkeyup=this.OnEnter @oninput=this.OnInput />`. Won't onInput be fired every single time the user inputs something, so for each alphabet the user enters?

Comment: Since it is now bounded to `@bind:oninput`?

Comment: Yes it is, it all depends on what behaviour you want from your input control.  Do you specifically not want the value to update until you change focus or hit enter?

Comment: The behaviour and sequence of events is driven by the Browser implementation, not Blazor or JS.  How you code the functionality you want is governed by that behaviour.  
 @Shingo and I are only the messengers!

Comment: Thank you! I will spend some more time trying to udnerstand this! This is my first time doing web dev, hence the confusion.